# How do __slots__ really work and how can you implement your own?

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter, instance-variables

I've been fooling around with `__slots__` and searching about them a little, but I'm still confused about some specifics:

I'm aware that `__slots__` generates some kind of descriptors:

```py
>>> class C:
...     __slots__ = ('x',)
...

>>> C.x
<member 'x' of 'C' objects>

>>> C.x.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of member_descriptor object at 0x7f001de183a8>

>>> C.x.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of member_descriptor object at 0x7f001de183a8>
```

But I was wondering: where are the values actually stored?

Because the common recipe/idiom I've seen so far for descriptors is:

```py
>>> class Descr:
...
...     def __init__(self, attrname):
...         self.attrname = attrname
...
...     def __get__(self, obj, cls):
...         return obj.__dict__[self.attrname]
...
...     def __set__(self, obj, val):
...         obj.__dict__[self.attrname] = val
...
... class C:
...
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
```

When used in addition with `__slots__`, there are two problems:

1. Clash with names:

```py
>>> class C:
...
...     __slots__ = ('x',)
...
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...
...     x = Descr('x')
...
Traceback (most recent call last)
 ...
ValueError: 'x' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

So a workaround is to name the actual attribute '_x'.

2. No `__dict__` (unless you explicitly add it to `__slots__`):

```py
>>> class C:
...
...     __slots__ = ('_x',)
...
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self._x = x
...
...     x = Descr('_x')
...

>>> c = C(0)

>>> c.x
Traceback (most recent call last)
 ...
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

So you have to use `getattr()` and `setattr()` instead.

You can end with a generic descriptor which can work with `__dict__` and `__slots__`:

```py
class WorksWithDictAndSlotsDescriptor:

    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self.attr_name = attr_name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            return instance.__dict__[self.attr_name]
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(instance, self.attr_name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        try:
            instance.__dict__[self.attr_name] = value
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(instance, self.attr_name, value)
```

(Which won't work as excepted if there is both `__slots__` and `__dict__`.)

But recently I've found a way to hijack the `__get__` and `__set__` method with a wrapper:

```py
def slot_wrapper(cls, slotname, slot, descriptor):
    '''Wrapper replacing a slot descriptor with another one'''

    class InnerDescr(descriptor):

        def __get__(self, obj, cls):
            print("Hijacking __get__ method of a member-descriptor")
            return slot.__get__(obj, cls)

        def __set__(self, obj, val):
            print("Hijacking __set__ method of a member-descriptor")
            slot.__set__(obj, val)

    return InnerDescr(slotname, cls)
```

(The use case is to add type checking and data validation, plus enforcing encapsulation.)

So after the creation of a class (or before using a metaclass) you can keep the same name for the slot and your descriptor.

Works well, but feels a little dirty... I think it may be better to implement my own slots to keep using one name for the descriptor. But I don't know how.

So here are some questions:

1. Where are the values actually stored (since there is no dict)? I was thinking it's something implemented in C and not directly accessible with Python code.
2. How can I implement a pure python equivalent without losing performance optimization?
3. Is it preferable to stick with my wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where are actually storerd the values (since there is no dict) ? I was thinking it's something implemented in C and not directly accessible with Python code.

Memory is allocated for the `PyObject *` pointers directly in the object itself. You can see the handling in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L2621-L2652). The generated descriptors will access the memory reserved for their slot in an object of the appropriate type.

> How can I implement a pure python equivalent without losing performance optimization?

You cannot. The closest you can get is something like extending `tuple`.

> It is prefarable to stick with my wrapper?

No. Don't name your slots the same thing as an attribute you want to be handled by some other descriptor. Doing so is like naming two non-slot descriptors the same thing; you're expressing two contradictory intentions for how you want to handle the attribute with that name.

Comment: Thanks for the first part, it's clear for me now. But about naming: Isn't it a waste to have two descriptors for one attribute? It's one lookup for nothing. The only thing I want is to add extra behavior: type checking and data validation. Plus the encapsulation is better that way, harder to bypass (not impossible but harder: you'll have to manipulate the class for that).

Comment: About the duplicate descriptors: It doesn't really waste lookups, as you were doing those either way. What you're wishing for is an optimization that could map the slot attribute into the custom setter's namespace somehow, to remove the call implicit in using the slot setter. But the slot setter itself doesn't need a lookup for its actual value, since it has a fixed offset; this is why it doesn't need the dict.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your overall outlook, I've been working on performative solutions for custom setters on member descriptors for some time now, and this is the best I've come up with so far:
(tested with Anaconda 2.3.0 (Python 3.4.3) on wine, and Python 3.5.2 on linux)

**Note: This solution does not attempt to be pythonic, nor does it serve as a direct answer to the question, but rather an alternative implementation to the desired result.**

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ( 'attr', )

attrget = A['attr'].__get__
attrset = A['attr'].__set__

def setter( obj, val ):
    if type( val ) is int:
        attrset( obj, val )
    else:
        raise TypeError( 'int type expected, got %s'%type( val ) )

setattr( A, 'attr', property( attrget, setter ) )
# ^ this is safer than A.__dict__['attr'] as a mapping_proxy is read-only
```

**Fun Fact:** For `i = A()`, while `i.attr` is less efficient (more CPU spikes), it's actually about ~20ns faster (relative to my machine) compared to the basic member_descriptor on average.
The same also applies to `i.attr = 0` without the custom setter.
(feel free to test for yourself, timeit should work similarly (except it includes the time for the for loop). (note that my tests didn't change the value), and make sure to run multiple tests)

here's the test results for Python 3.5.2 on linux:

```
10000 iterations; threshold of min + 250ns:
________code___|_______min______|_______max______|_______avg______|_efficiency
⡇⢠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡄⠀⢰⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⣿⣾⣴⣄⣤⣄⣄⣰⣦⣤⣧⣰⣼⣤⣤⣆⡀⡀⢀⣄⣠⣀⣴⣶⣦⣤⣤⣦⣶⣄⣄⣠⣄⣴⣤⣶⣸⣦⣤⣤⣴⣴⣴⣷⣶⣴⣦⣤⣶⣆⣤⣤⣦⣶⣤⣴⣠⣷⣤⣶⣾⣷⣤⣆
    i.mdsc = 1 |      564.964ns |    17341.983ns |      638.568ns |  88.473%
⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⢠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⣷⣶⣶⣴⣤⣤⣦⣶⣶⣦⣧⣼⣼⣴⣄⣦⡄⣄⣀⣄⣴⡄⣼⣾⣶⣦⣴⣧⣶⣄⣄⣴⣦⣾⣴⣴⣤⣦⣆⣶⣴⣤⣴⣷⣿⣼⣾⣦⣷⣦⣧⣾⣦⣿⣤⣴⣤⣿⣤⣧⣾⣷⣶⣧
    i.prop = 1 |      538.013ns |     8267.001ns |      624.045ns |  86.214%
10000 iterations; threshold of min + 175ns:
____code___|_______min______|_______max______|_______avg______|_efficiency
⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡆
⣇⣴⣠⣤⣠⣄⣤⣄⣀⣀⣀⡀⣀⣀⣀⣄⣠⣠⣄⣦⣤⣤⣄⣤⣤⣠⣤⣧⣤⣤⣠⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣼⣤⣤⣤⣶⣤⣶⣦⣤⣀⣄⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣶⣦⣷⣤⣶⣄⣧
    i.mdsc |      364.962ns |    27579.023ns |      411.621ns |  88.665%
⡇⢠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⣷⣾⣦⣦⣴⣠⣿⣦⣠⣠⣄⣀⣄⡄⣠⣴⣠⣤⣴⣴⣦⣼⣤⣦⣤⣤⣤⣧⣴⣶⣦⣶⣶⣶⣶⣶⣦⣶⣶⣶⣷⣿⣷⣿⣷⣾⣶⣶⣶⣾⣾⣾⣶⣶⣴⣶⣴⣾⣷⣿⣿⣷⣶⣶
    i.prop |      341.039ns |     2000.015ns |      400.054ns |  85.248%
```

Finally, if you downvote this answer, please explain why.
(please do not downvote if your tests do not compare to mine)
^ my results are just an example to show a small boost in performance, and should not be taken at face value.